# Building a project with 2 Configurations for single Solution wide Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

So i have 1 project in my solution that i need to write code like

```
#if VERSION1
Do something
#endif
#if VERSION2
Do something else
#endif
```

The project has 2 Configurations, Version1 and Version2. One with VERSION1 as the conditional compilation symbol and one with the other. These configurations are only for this project. When building the entire solution as Debug or release can i get Visual Studio to build both Version1 and 2 Config for that project? Under solution properties i can only seem to build one

I've just talking about a local build not using msbuild